# How to find specific keyword in a string?

Tags: kotlin

I have following code:

```
val contains = jobAd.toString().lowercase()
                .contains(keyword.lowercase())
```

Problem is its getting hit even the string have "javascript". But i only want it to behit when it's actually the word java.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I don't use Kotlin, but based on other programming languages, you'll either have to use a regex or split the string based on spaces (and punctuation) and search that list/array.

Comment: please clarify more your question

Comment: In a nutshell `val contains = jobAd.toString().contains(Regex("java(?!\\s*script)"))`. Although you probably also need the `IGNORE_CASE` option for the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match only an entire word, you can use word boundaries in a regular expression like this:

```
fun String.findWord(word: String) = "\\b$word\\b".toRegex().containsMatchIn(this)
```

Then you can write for instance:

```
"I like Java!".findWord("Java") // true
"I like JavaScript".findWord("Java") // false
```

Note that this is case sensitive and not very robust, because for instance, it is possible to inject a regular expression. This is just to give you the general idea.